# ForEach Inside ForEach in Reactive Forms Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, angular-forms

How can i forEach the expiration_date since i have an ingredient that is the same but has different expiration date. What i have in mind is that i should have a dropdown which could select the ingredient and output each different expiration date. My problem how can i do ForEach inside of my Foreach? Here's my stackblitz link.

[CODE LINK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-sgqrzp?file=app/app.component.ts)

> TS

```
 patchValues() {
    let rows = this.addForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.ingredients.forEach(data => {
      rows.push(this.fb.group({
      ingredient_id: data.id,
      qty_available: data.qty_available,
      qty: ['', Validators.required],
      expiration_date: "How to ForEach HERE?",
    }))
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not Create/Use defined object class and defined object array to define your data instead of this big chuck of nested object definition/JSON ?

An ingredient is made of an id,name and an array of warehouseItem

a warehouseItem is name of an id,name,total stock etc

Create a list of ingredients and retrieve the index depending on the row you are on and then add the possible result to the select choice.

heres a small example I did: https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-fkhayr

Comment: I cant that since The warehouse_items is already provided by the backend. Its already inside of the ingredients

Comment: you can automaticaly map the response from the backend to those object; they just need the same property name.I assume the backend returns a list of ingredients

Comment: post code/logic on how your angular front-end is receiving info from backend.Can't really help with current code as your JSON code is all static inside the ts file and no code dealing with retrieving/mapping JSON data from backend;if you have never done this then you need to start there first.

Comment: Thats how my code returns from the backend. When ngOnInit runs, it suddenly calls the patchValues(). The warehouse_items is already inside of ingredients

Comment: that is not a backend! ; thats just static data on your front-end(angular) in JSON form but regardless, there is nothing stopping you from removing all the JSON and replace it with objects/array of objects and then show the obj values like I did for the first row in my example; ill update it with the  ingredient drop down too.

Comment: Yes thats not the backend. its the json response coming from the backend. That is the structure of the json. Could you implement my json response to your code?

Comment: One thing. The ingredient dropdown should be the same ingredient name/id. If ingredient name/id is different it should create a new row. If you click the dropdown, it should filter out the expiry date